# Android How to get amplitude for different frequencies with the help of SensorEvent

Tags: java, android, sensors, android-sensors, sensormanager

I want to calculate vibration while vehicle is moving. I am getting this data in onSensorChanged event. I need to calculate vibration for 12hz, 24hz and 36hz.

```
@Override    
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (started) {

        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();


        final float alpha = 0.8f;
        gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
        gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
        gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

        accelerometer_data[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
        accelerometer_data[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
        accelerometer_data[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];




        long differ = (timestamp - previousTime);


        if (differ > 1500 ){
            Log.e(Tag, rotation_per_second * accelerometer_data[0]+"--12hz");
            Log.e(Tag, rotation_per_second *2* accelerometer_data[1]+ "--24hz");
            Log.e(Tag, rotation_per_second *3* accelerometer_data[2]+"--36hz");
            previousTime = timestamp;




        }

        else
        {

            //Log.e(Tag, "Difference = "+differ+"");
        }





        AccelData data = new AccelData(timestamp,  accelerometer_data[0], accelerometer_data[1], accelerometer_data[2]);
        sensorData.add(data);


    }
}
```

rotation_per_second is frequency that I am getting when vehicle is moving. For example if vehicle is moving at the speed of 60mph I am getting 12hz frequency. Now I want to calculate amplitude for 12hz, 24hz and 36hz from onSensorChanged event.

Comment: so do you have a question, or you just want to say what you want to do?

Comment: I've a question, am not sure how to get amplitude for these frequencies.